# Possible to send data from a Pi Pico via USB while running CircuitPython?

Tags: usb, serial, uart, pi-pico, circuitpython

I have a question on the interaction between Pi Pico, CircuitPython, and USB. I need a way to send a data stream *from* the Pico to another computer where it will be received on a USB port (it's the only possible input port). Do I assume correctly that I cannot use the Pico's USB port for that, because it is already used by CircuitPython for its file system and/or REPL? Does that mean that in order to develop with CircuitPython, I would have to send the data on UART instead and use a TTL-to-USB converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via USB HID, re. the Pico works as a Keyboard, sending data to a connected computer.

Comment: Thanks. I see there are examples/ tutorials that use CircuitPython to define mouse or keyboard, so I guess it must be possible to do both at the same time. Alas, it is probably more work to define custom HID device with more sensor values than just mouse X/ Y. Definitely looking into it, perhaps it must be done in lower levels than CircuitPython.

Comment: This seems like a starting point to implement something: https://learn.adafruit.com/custom-hid-devices-in-circuitpython - so indeed, one has to add the custom device to the boot process, and thus they can coexist with the CircuitPython environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also communicate with host via USB serial device - a better choice for sensor data perhaps; this works in in C from pico so should be possible with circuit python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121239)